# In the Windows version of Scrivener for Screenplay formatting, how do format for action/dialogue/shot?

Tags: formatting, screenwriting, scrivener

There is a way to automatically change the indices to respect whether it is a line of dialogue or a description of the setting, but I can't find a way to bring the menu up consistently when hitting "enter" and able to select something.

[image: menu brought up when hitting return]

When this menu is clicked, nothing seems to happen or changes.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you will want to enter Screenwritng Mode (Format -> Screenwriting). This gives you a dropdown in the footer (bottom right corner) which contains these options. Select your text, click on the dropdown, and then select from the list...does that help?

Comment: I found it. Would you like to submit this as an answer? https://i.imgur.com/Bll8fw1.png

Answer (score 2):

To format a screenplay in Scrivener:

1. Turn on Screenwriting Mode.

   To do this, select Format-> Screenwriting from the menu bar.
2. Select the text you wish to format, click on the dropdown menu in the bottom right-hand corner, and then select the desired format from the list.